# How to prevent a column from being reordered in wpf

Tags: .net, wpf

I have written a wpf code for a grid, it has 5-6 columns, the first one being the name. I want to freeze this column, meaning that it should not be movable. 
I tried doing this

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="Name" CanUserReorder="False">
```

but the problem with this code is, I cannot move my name column to replace another column , but I can drag any other column in its place. For eg.. I can drag my shortName column in place of name column.

I want that the name column should not move at all but the other columns can be movable. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.frozencolumncount(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Frozen columns are always the leftmost columns in display order. You cannot drag frozen columns into the group of unfrozen columns or drag unfrozen columns into the group of frozen columns.

so setting `FrozenColumnCount ="1"` should do the trick

```
    <DataGrid FrozenColumnCount="1" CanUserReorderColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="#1"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="#2"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="#3"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```